# Does plainText password over https remains secure when stored in the client.?

Tags: cookies, https, password-encryption, cookiestore

When setting Cookiee on the server with properties(httpOnly and secure=true), does that mean it will only be secured during the communication beween server and client, but not after that?
In other words, if the value was originally in plainText -will it also be stored on the client side with plainText (after traveling with https ) -making it unsafe/vulnerable?

1) Do passwords needs to be always encrypt befors sending (even when using https)?

2) Where is httpCookiee (with secure=true) stored? and is this storage access is protected?

Comment: One could always view cookies using Firebug/Chrome Dev. Tools/`document.cookie` and **no** cookies are not encrypted, so use something like SID instead. HTTPS implements SSL(/TLS?) so is encrypted by RSA

Comment: And you don't need to always encrypt passwords, only when **you want to secure your clients' security**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want store the password.

What you need is store some "user is already authenticated" flag.

After all, you should learn about "digest access authentification". Storing hashed data is always plus.

This answer is too short, mainly bacause here is too much possibilities - and too much open questions.

Handling returning users:

You can manage (server side) an session database. in the cookie you storing only session ID. when the user authenticate  itself, you're store into your server side database his status: "logged in". when he log out, you change in the DB status: "logged off".

Handling returning users has nothing with "storing passwords" in any way. You for  example can authenticate users by external auth-services, like open-id, twitter, facebook etc., you're only storing his status by some session-ID or similar.

Browsers usually can store user-names/passwords, but this all time **should be** the user responsibility. When the user want only remeber his passwords, you **should not** store it in any way.

Why you want complicating your app and security mechanisms with storing encrypted passwords in cookies - what is not a correct solution - from any point of view?

Simple flow:

- When an *new* user comes to your site - you assign him an new session-ID and store the SID into a cookie
- when he login (via https) - you're store in your DB = "sessionID" -> "logged in"
- when he return after a week, you can (server side) either accept his session-ID from the cookie - and from DB you can get his "logged-in" status, or, you can force login him once again (for example because of expiration)
- all of the above is without any risk storing passwords in any way

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually i was hoping to use that cookiee when the user return to my site (so he won't need to login). Is it better to use hashed over just incrypt it before sending(for example, with rijndaelmanaged class) ?

Comment: so,for my impression, it doesn't even have to be a sid , it can even be GUID or anything else(except for the real password) and as long as the cookiee doesn't expire user could log

Comment: so, for my impression, it doesn't even have to be a SID , it can even be GUID or anything else(except for the real password) and as long as the cookiee doesn't expire user could log automatically.(it is more like an alternative password that the server initiate for certain time of use and a certain computer) correct?

Comment: Correct. I'm mostly using perl and Plack::Middleware::Session. It handles everything from generation unique session-ID, setting/fetching cookies, keeps session state and store data in caches. So i don't really care about it's implementation. I only need if( !$session->{loggedin} ) { do_login(); } Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think so. Because even with secure flag, cookie will be stored in browser cache in plain text

2) It depends on browsers and OS. For Safari in Mac, you can find it in your ~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.plist You can see cookies with Secure flag but in plain text. It may be protected so only owner can see, but it never be good idea to have plain password anywhere in your computer

Comment: thank you, I understand everything except for the part "...it may be protected so only owner can see...". how is it protected?

Comment: I mean cookie directory basically can not be viewed by any other users of the computer. More specifically user A and user B share a pc and both has different login user each, then user A cannot see user B's cookie directory. But if the pc is stolen or hack or anything happen, password is stored in plain text and it may be revealed easily.

Answer (score 0):

Once the secure flag is set to true, the cookie will be stored encrypted in the client even after the browser is closed. As you say it is unsafe/vulnerable.

Resp. 1)
 Passwords can be encrypted before sending using Javascript, but it doesn't make much sense because https is doing the encryption for you.

Resp. 2)
 The cookies are stored in the browser folder. Anybody can open the folder and see the cookies with a text editor.

The browser will handle the passwords for you. Just using a <input type="password"> and using SSL is secure enough.
And, avoid at all costs storing passwords in cookies.

Comment: why it is so bed to store encrypt passwoed in a cookiee?

Comment: The cookie is so easy to spoof. Anybody can get it with a packet sniffer because cookies are sent in every request to the server.

Comment: Or if the hacker have access to the client machine he could just open the cookies with a text editor.
Once you have the cookie, it's a matter of time to decrypt it by dictionary attacks, brute force or by crashing the encrypt algorithm. If it's SHA128 or MD5 it shouldn't take more than 2 months.